# Thread 1: Program received signal:"Sigbart"

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I try to run my app on my iPhone, I get "

> Thread 1: Program received
> signal:"Sigbart"

xCode say that points to     `[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "global.h"
#import "golfbaner.h" 

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize banenavn;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   
    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"Alsten Golfklubb",
                     @"Arendal og Omegn Golfklubb",
                     @"Asker Golfklubb",
                     @"Askim Golfklubb",
                     @"Atlungstad Golfklubb",
                     @"Aurskog Golfpark",
                     @"Ballerud Golfklubb",
                     @"Bamble Golfklubb",
                     @"Bergen Golfklubb",
                     @"Bjorli Golfklubb",
                     @"Bjørnefjorden Golfklubb",
                     @"Bjaavann Golfklubb",
                     @"Bodø Golfbane",
                     @"Borre Golfbane",
                     @"Borregaard Golfklubb",
                     @"Brønnøysund Golfklubb",
                     @"Byneset Golfklubb",
                     @"Bærum Golfklubb",
                     @"Drammen Golfklubb",
                     @"Drøbak Golfklubb",
                     @"Egersund Golfklubb",
                     @"Eidskog Golfklubb",
                     @"Eiker Golfklubb",
                     @"Ekholt Golfklubb",
                     @"Elverum Golfklubb",
                     @"Fana Golfklubb",
                     @"Fet Golfklubb",
                     @"Frosta Golfklubb",
                     @"Geilo Golfklubb",
                     @"Giske Golfklubb",
                     @"Gjerdrum Golfpark",
                     @"Gjersjøen Golfklubb",
                     @"Gjøvik og Toten Golfklubb",
                     @"Gran Golfklubb",
                     @"Grenland Golfklubb",
                     @"Grimstad Golfklubb",
                     @"Grini Golfklubb",
                     @"Groruddalen Golfklubb",
                     @"Grønmo Golfklubb",
                     @"Hafjell Golfklubb",
                     @"Haga Golfpark",
                     @"Hakadal Golfklubb",
                     @"Halden Golfklubb",
                     @"Hallingdal Golfklubb",
                     @"Hammerfest og Kvalsund Golfklubb",
                     @"Hardanger Golfklubb",
                     @"Harstad Golfklubb",
                     @"Haugaland Golfklubb",
                     @"Hauger Golf",
                     @"Haugesund Golfklubb",
                     @"Helgeland Golfklubb",
                     @"Hemsedal Golfklubb",
                     @"Herdla Golfklubb",
                     @"Hitra Golfklubb",
                     @"Hof Golfklubb",
                     @"Holtsmark Golfklubb",
                     @"Hovden Golfklubb",
                     @"Hurum Golfklubb",
                     @"Huseby og Hankø Golfklubb",
                     @"Hvaler Golfklubb",
                     @"Hvam Golfklubb",
                     @"Jæren Golfklubb",
                     @"Karasjok Golfklubb",
                     @"Karmøy Golfklubb",
                     @"Kjekstad Golfklubb",
                     @"Klæbu Golfklubb",
                     @"Kongsberg Golfklubb",
                     @"Kongsvinger Golfklubb",
                     @"Kragerø Golfklubb",
                     @"Kristiansand Golfklubb",
                     @"Kristiansund og Omegn Golfklubb",
                     @"Krokhol Golfklubb",
                     @"Kvinesdal og Omegn Golfklubb",
                     @"Kvinnherad Golfklubb",
                     @"Kvitfjell",
                     @"Larvik Golfklubb",
                     @"Lillehammer Golf Park",
                     @"Lillestrøm Golfklubb",
                     @"Lofoten Golf Links",
                     @"Lommedalen Golfklubb",
                     @"Losby Golfklubb",
                     @"Lærdal Golfklubb",
                     @"Lønne Golfklubb",
                     @"Mandal Golfklubb",
                     @"Meland Golfklubb",
                     @"Midt-Troms Golfklubb",
                     @"Miklagard Golfklubb",
                     @"Mjøsen Golfklubb",
                     @"Moa Golfklubb",
                     @"Modum Golfklubb",
                     @"Molde Golfklubb",
                     @"Moss og Rygge Golfklubb",
                     @"Mørk Golfklubb",
                     @"Namdal Golfklubb",
                     @"Namsos Golfklubb",
                     @"Narvik Golfklubb",
                     @"Nes Golfklubb",
                     @"Nittedal Golfklubb",
                     @"Nordfjord Golfklubb",
                     @"Nordvegen Golfklubb",
                     @"Norefjell Golfklubb",
                     @"Norsjø og Omegn Golfklubb",
                     @"North Cape Golf Club",
                     @"Nærøysund Golfklubb",
                     @"Nøtterøy Golfklubb",
                     @"Odda Golfklubb",
                     @"Ogna Golfklubb",
                     @"Onsøy Golfklubb",
                     @"Oppdal Golfklubb",
                     @"Oppegård Golfklubb",
                     @"Oslo Golfklubb",
                     @"Oustøen Country Club",
                     @"Polarsirkelen Golf",
                     @"Preikestolen Golfklubb",
                     @"Randaberg Golfklubb",
                     @"Randsfjorden Golfklubb",
                     @"Rauma Golfklubb",
                     @"Re Golfklubb",
                     @"Ringerike Golfklubb",
                     @"Rygge Flystasjon Golf Club",
                     @"Røros Golfklubb",
                     @"Salten Golfklubb",
                     @"Sandane Golfklubb",
                     @"Sande Golfklubb",
                     @"Sandefjord Golfklubb",
                     @"Sandnes Golfklubb",
                     @"Sauda Golfklubb",
                     @"Selbu Golfklubb",
                     @"Selje Golfklubb",
                     @"Setesdal Golfklubb",
                     @"Skei Golfklubb",
                     @"Ski Golfklubb",
                     @"Skjeberg Golfklubb",
                     @"Smøla Golfklubb",
                     @"Sola Golfklubb",
                     @"Solastranden Golfklubb",
                     @"Solum Golfklubb",
                     @"Soon Golfklubb",
                     @"Sorknes Golfklubb",
                     @"Sotra Golfklubb",
                     @"Stavanger Golfklubb",
                     @"Steinkjer Golfklubb",
                     @"Stiklestad Golfklubb",
                     @"Stjørdal Golfklubb",
                     @"Stord Golfklubb",
                     @"Stranda Golfklubb",
                     @"Stryn Golfklubb",
                     @"Sunndal Golfklubb",
                     @"Sunnfjord Golfklubb",
                     @"Sunnmøre Golfklubb",
                     @"Surnadal Golfklubb",
                     @"Tjøme Golfklubb",
                     @"Tromsø Golfklubb",
                     @"Trondheim Golfklubb",
                     @"Trysil Golfklubb",
                     @"Tyrifjord Golfklubb",
                     @"Ullensaker Golfklubb",
                     @"Valdres Golfklubb",
                     @"Vanylven Golfklubb",
                     @"Varanger Golfklubb",
                     @"Vesterålen Golfklubb",
                     @"Vestfold Golfklubb",
                     @"Vildmarken Golfklubb",
                     @"Volda Golfklubb",
                     @"Voss Golfklubb",
                     @"Vrådal Golfklubb",
                     @"Østmarka Golfklubb",
                     @"Øya Golfpark",
                     @"Ålesund Golfklubb",
                     nil];
    
    self.banenavn = temp;
    [temp release];
    
    self.title = @"Golfbaner i Norge";
    
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
 */

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{           
    return [banenavn count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [banenavn objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    golf = [banenavn objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    
    golfbaner *detailViewController = [[golfbaner alloc] initWithNibName:@"Golfbaner" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{  
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    
    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that's SIGABRT meaning the Abort Signal.

Check if detailViewController is 'nil' or not, it probably is.

Also you probably want "Golf Banner" unless this is something that is the bane of all golfers (which it could be)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `self` is on a `UINavigationController` added as root ou with push? Maybe it does't have a navigationController or is a modal inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

A few different things could be happening. First self.navigationController is likely either dealloced or not of type NavigationController. Stick a break point on the push and do
po self.navigationController 
in the gdb console to be sure. It will either say something like invalid object which means its released or it will tell you the object type. Make sure it either is or extends UINavigationController. Secondly have a look at the detailViewController in gdb the same way and make sure it is a valid UIViewController. One of these two objects is your culprit.